# Oracle update query using jdbi UPDATED ONLY SOME COLUMNS not all

Tags: oracle, transactions, jdbi

I know this is strange behaviour, but I'm clearly missing something when handling oracle connection or transaction.

Below is my update query in jdbi which is trying to update 4 columns.

```
UPDATE TASK
   SET TASK_STATUS = 'closed',
       IS_DIRTY = 0,
       UPDATED_BY = :updatedBy,
       UPDATED_AT = sysdate
 WHERE SOURCE_TASK_ID = :taskId
   AND SOURCE_SYSTEM = :sourceSystem
```

And the update statement returns true (means updated). but When I checked in the table only Updated_by and updated_at got updated, not the Task_status and is_dirty (And Only one row exist in the table).

Strangely sometimes it updates all the column.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: This isn't possible AFAIK, so my guess is that your data has a problem.  It is even less likely that an update statement would complete but only update some but not all columns in the `SET` clause.

Comment: Or you might have some trigger on table for UPDATE action which set it back to original value.

Answer (score 0):

Except there are some `triggers`, it is not possible in oracle that some columns are updated and some are not. This is not at all possible.

See the example below:

**Sample table creation:**

> ```
> SQL> CREATE TABLE TASK (
>   2      SOURCE_TASK_ID   NUMBER,
>   3      SOURCE_SYSTEM    VARCHAR2(100),
>   4      TASK_STATUS      VARCHAR2(100),
>   5      IS_DIRTY         NUMBER,
>   6      UPDATED_BY       VARCHAR2(100),
>   7      UPDATED_AT       DATE
>   8  );
>
> Table created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Inserting the data to the table:**

> ```
> SQL>
> SQL> INSERT INTO TASK VALUES (
>   2      1,
>   3      'SO',
>   4      'open',
>   5      1,
>   6      NULL,
>   7      NULL
>   8  );
>
> 1 row created.
>
> SQL> COMMIT;
>
> Commit complete.
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Data in the table as of now:**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TASK;
>
> SOURCE_TASK_ID SOURCE_SYS TASK_STATU IS_DIRTY UPDATED_BY   UPDATED_AT
> -------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------------ ---------------
>              1 SO         open            0                
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Normal update in the table:**

> ```
> SQL> UPDATE TASK
>   2  SET
>   3      TASK_STATUS = 'closed',
>   4      IS_DIRTY = 0,
>   5      UPDATED_BY = 'Tejash',
>   6      UPDATED_AT = SYSDATE
>   7  WHERE
>   8      SOURCE_TASK_ID = 1
>   9      AND SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'SO';
>
> 1 row updated.
>
> SQL>
> SQL> COMMIT;
> ```

**selecting the data from the table now.**

> ```
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TASK;
>
> SOURCE_TASK_ID SOURCE_SYS TASK_STATU IS_DIRTY UPDATED_BY   UPDATED_AT
> -------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------------ ---------------
>              1 SO         closed            0 Tejash       03-JAN-20
>
> SQL>
> ```

Ohh, all the columns are updated.

Now, Let's create a situation where some columns are not updated.

**Deleting and Inserting the new records from the table:**

> ```
> SQL> DELETE FROM TASK;
>
> 1 row deleted.
>
> SQL> COMMIT;
>
> Commit complete.
>
> SQL> INSERT INTO TASK VALUES (
>   2      1,
>   3      'SO',
>   4      'open',
>   5      1,
>   6      NULL,
>   7      NULL
>   8  );
>
> 1 row created.
>
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TASK;
>
> SOURCE_TASK_ID SOURCE_SYS TASK_STATU IS_DIRTY UPDATED_BY   UPDATED_AT
> -------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------------ ---------------
>              1 SO         open              1
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Now, creating the trigger to manipulate the update:**

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TASK_TRG BEFORE
>   2      UPDATE ON TASK
>   3      FOR EACH ROW
>   4  BEGIN
>   5      IF :NEW.UPDATED_BY <> 'Tejash' THEN -- any condition
>   6          :NEW.TASK_STATUS := :OLD.TASK_STATUS;
>   7          :NEW.IS_DIRTY := :OLD.IS_DIRTY;
>   8      END IF;
>   9  END;
>  10  /
>
> Trigger created.
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Let us try to update the data on the table now.**

> ```
> SQL> UPDATE TASK
>   2  SET
>   3      TASK_STATUS = 'closed',
>   4      IS_DIRTY = 0,
>   5      UPDATED_BY = 'Not Tejash', -- see this
>   6      UPDATED_AT = SYSDATE
>   7  WHERE
>   8      SOURCE_TASK_ID = 1
>   9      AND SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'SO';
>
> 1 row updated.
>
> SQL>
> SQL> COMMIT;
>
> Commit complete.
>
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TASK;
>
> SOURCE_TASK_ID SOURCE_SYS TASK_STATU IS_DIRTY UPDATED_BY   UPDATED_AT
> -------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------------ ---------------
>              1 SO         open              1 Not Tejash   03-JAN-20
>
> SQL>
> ```

See value of the `TASK_STATUS` and `IS_DIRTY` is not changed.

**Let's try to update the table with `UPDATED_BY = 'Tejash'`**

> ```
> SQL> UPDATE TASK
>   2  SET
>   3      TASK_STATUS = 'closed',
>   4      IS_DIRTY = 0,
>   5      UPDATED_BY = 'Tejash', -- see this
>   6      UPDATED_AT = SYSDATE
>   7  WHERE
>   8      SOURCE_TASK_ID = 1
>   9      AND SOURCE_SYSTEM = 'SO';
>
> 1 row updated.
>
> SQL> COMMIT;
>
> Commit complete.
>
> SQL> SELECT * FROM TASK;
>
> SOURCE_TASK_ID SOURCE_SYS TASK_STATU IS_DIRTY UPDATED_BY   UPDATED_AT
> -------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ------------ ---------------
>              1 SO         closed            0 Tejash       03-JAN-20
>
> SQL>
> ```

OK!! Now it is updated. so *sometimes it is updating the column value and sometimes not* because There is some condition in the trigger which changes the value in between. (This must be the reason for the strange behavior that you are facing)

If you want to see if any trigger is created on your table then you can check it in **ALL_TRIGGERS** view as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      OWNER,
>   3      TRIGGER_NAME,
>   4      TABLE_OWNER,
>   5      TABLE_NAME,
>   6      TRIGGER_TYPE,
>   7      TRIGGERING_EVENT
>   8  FROM
>   9      ALL_TRIGGERS
>  10  WHERE
>  11      TABLE_NAME = 'TASK';
>
> OWNER      TRIGGER_NAME    TABLE_OWNE TABLE_NAME TRIGGER_TYPE         TRIGGERING
> ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
> TEJASH     TASK_TRG        TEJASH     TASK       BEFORE EACH ROW      UPDATE
>
> SQL>
> ```

Hope, It will be useful to you and clears your doubt.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are triggers on that table
    select * from dba_triggers where table_name = 'TASK';

If Db said that dba_triggers does not exist, try querying from all_triggers